# HashMap to find all the pairs that add up to give a number k

Tags: java, hashmap

I wanted to find all the pairs in an array that sum up to give a number K. I was thinking of using the HashMap technique in java. The problem with this is that the array can have duplicate entries. How to store multiple values for the same key? I dont want to use any external libraries like MultiMap.
Say for instance the array is {2,4,3,2,1} and the number k=5.
The technique should give the indices of all the pairs that sum upto 5.
output should be (0,2) (2,3) (1,4)

Thank you.

This is the code I wrote

```
class NewClass {

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
   int arr[]={2,4,3,2,1},k=5;
   HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();

   int i;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
       if(map.containsKey(arr[i])){
           ArrayList<Integer> offset=map.get(arr[i]);
           offset.add(i);
           map.put(arr[i], offset);
       }
       else{
           ArrayList<Integer> offset=new ArrayList<>();
           offset.add(i);
           map.put(arr[i], offset);
       }        
   }

   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
       if(map.containsKey(k-arr[i])){
           ArrayList<Integer> offset=map.get(arr[i]);
           for(int a:offset){
               System.out.println(i+" "+a);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

}

The O/P which I got is

0 0
0 3
1 1
2 2
3 0
3 3
4 4

Can you please tell me what is wrong with this code? Please bear with me as I am new to coding.

Comment: What about this problem lends itself to a `Map`?  I see nothing here that would...

Comment: This time I'm damn sure this is a homework assignment. No. Hashmap is a bad idea for this. Try a simple int array. Input all the numbers in that array. Sort that array ascending. Eliminate all the numbers greater than your sum. Then pick a number from beginning (say n) and corresponding (sum-n) from the end of the array. So you get the pairs [n, sum-n] as you needed.

Comment: Why do you think a hash map technique is a good approach? What is the purpose of storing multiple values for the same key? From your output, it's clear that you need to consider the index of all duplicate values.

Comment: You can store multiple values for the same key by making your value a `Collection` of some sort. Although, I still don't understand why you think using a `Map` would be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Using a map from value to index would bring down the time complexity from O(n^2) to almost O(n). It is a valid approach.

Comment: @Henry I don't understand how a map would reduce the amount of times you need to search every pair of numbers.

Comment: @MxyL see the answer of Stephen C.

Comment: @Henry, I see why it would be O(n). That approach would require a single loop as opposed to checking every pair.

Comment: @AshisKumarSahoo sorting the array would alter the original offsets of numbers. And I am more concerned about their offsets rather than the numbers itself.

Comment: @AkashSingh You have indicated (1,4) as one of your valid results. How is that preserving the offset? It should rather be (4,1) if offset is preserved.

Answer (score 6):

We could solve the problem for you, but then you wouldn't learn anything.  So I'll give you a couple of hints:

- If you have A and B that need to add up to N, and you know A, then B must be N - A
- Create a hashmap that maps from numbers to the list of offsets in the original array at which the numbers occur.

The rest is just using / developing your problem solving and programming skills.  Think about it.  Have a go at coding it.  If you get stuck, show us what you've done and ask a concrete question about it.

Comment: I edited the question and inserted my code. Can you please tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: @AkashSingh you fetch the wrong list of elements, in the second loop do `ArrayList<Integer> offset=map.get(k - arr[i]);`. To suppress the duplicate pairs (0,2 and 2,0) you could check that the first index is <= the second.